# How to find max value of a map whose value is a List in Java8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Map`:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Students>> studentsInClass
```

I can find the class having the max number of `Student`s by iterating over the `Map` and assign it to an `int` and comparing.

I'd like to know what is the optimal and Java 8 way of doing it. I want to get the highest `List` size of all the values in the `Map`.

Comment: 1. program to interface -- `List<Student>` 2. Share what you tried and didn't work.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: You can easily use the [powerful Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) from Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to get the highest list size in the map

If I get correctly what you mean then you should try this:

```
int maxSize = studentsInClass.values()
                             .stream()
                             .map(List::size)
                             .max(naturalOrder())
                             .orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stream` has a `max` method that can be used to find the `max` element of the `Stream` according to any property of the elements of the `Stream`.

```
String largestClassName = 
    studentsInClass.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .orElse(null); // default value for when the Map is empty
```

or (without a default value):

```
Optional<String> largestClassName = 
    studentsInClass.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Or, if you need the size of the largest class (instead of the name of that class):

```
int maxClassSize = 
    studentsInClass.values()
                   .stream()
                   .mapToInt(List::size)
                   .max();
                   .orElse(0); // default value for when the Map is empty
```

or (without a default value):

```
OptionalInt maxClassSize = 
    studentsInClass.values()
                   .stream()
                   .mapToInt(List::size)
                   .max();
```